# .hasNext() not work correctly

Tags: java

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    // check if the scanner has a token
    System.out.println(scanner.hasNext());

    // print the rest of the string
    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());

    // check if the scanner has a token after printing the line
    System.out.println(scanner.hasNext());
```

When I run this code and enter:

> Hi

print these in console:

```
true
Hi
```

but never program ended or print `false`.What's the problem?

Comment: In addition to @Eran's answer, please also realize that Scanner is not only used for reading from System.in, it could be from a file.  In which case it would maybe print false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/**
 * Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input.
 * This method may block while waiting for input to scan.
 * The scanner does not advance past any input.
 *
 * @return true if and only if this scanner has another token
 * @throws IllegalStateException if this scanner is closed
 * @see java.util.Iterator
 */
public boolean hasNext()
```

`hasNext()` blocks while waiting for input. That's why the second call to `System.out.println(scanner.hasNext());` prints nothing and the program doesn't end.

If your Scanner was reading data from a file instead of from the standard input, `hasNext()` would have returned false when reaching the end of the file.

Comment: Imagin I want  'while(scanner.hasNext())'
so wath can I do?

Comment: @KaavehMohamedi When reading input from standard input, you can choose some input that marks the end of input. For example : `while (!(line = scanner.nextLine()).equals("quit"))

Comment: Yes that's right! but when I solving problem in competitive programming like CodeForces.com or others I can't choose.

Comment: @KaavehMohamedi Perhaps you should elaborate more on what your code is supposed to do. Is the input for your code supposed to come from standard input?

Comment: You can see this:
write a program that lists all the different words in the input text.
Input:
The input is a text with no more than 5000 lines. An input line has at most 200 characters.

Output:
Your output should give a list of different words that appears in the input text, one in a line.You can be sure that he number of distinct words in the text does not exceed 5000.

Sample Input:

Adventures in Disneyland
Two blondes were going to Disneyland when they came to a fork in the
road. The sign read: "Disneyland Left."
So they went home.

Comment: @KaavehMohamedi Well, if you are told the input has at most 5000 lines, just count the number of lines and quit when either scanner.nextLine() returns null or once you've read 5000 lines.

Comment: my problem is reading! while (input.hasNext()) and in this body: temp= input.next(); but at the end program never exit from loop! because input.hasNext() never return anything so while condition never check again!

Comment: @KaavehMohamedi Don't use input.hasNext. Just write `int count=0;while (count < 5000 && (line = scanner.nextLine()) != null) {...count++;...}`

Answer (score 1):

you are reading data from console that's why its does not return false value. instead of try to read data from file it sure works because when file read reach at the end of file then it will returns false because there if is no value.